# How to use video in django?

Tags: django, video

can anyone suggest me how to use video in django application? I tried different ways but didn't work.

````
<source src="/home/sahil/Desktop/LearnHtmlCss/MyLearnHtml/media/DanceMonkey.mp4"type="video/mp4">
</video>```
even i used 
```{% media 'DanceMonkey.mp4' %}```
I have setup my media files in seetings.py
```Media_Dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')    MEDIA_ROOT = [Media_Dir,]    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'```
under my urls.py ```+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You must use url in src, not path. For example:
model:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    videofile = models.FileField(upload_to='xxx', verbose_name='video')
```

template:

```
...
source src="{{ video.url }}"
```

Or if you want use video without model, something like this:

```
source src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/video.mp4"
```

Comment: I get my file path after applying query set i store that i one variable and pass that in context dict
test = DanceMonkey.mp4
return render(request,'test.html,{video:test})
i passed in src {{video.url}}
but still my video is not play

Comment: look at the final html code and make sure that the video file exists at the specified url